# How can I set up seconds as int data type without this eror?

Tags: java, webdriverwait

When I tried to create an exemplar of WebdriverWait , I faced an issue with data types I believe. I can't setup seconds in the brackets because of it says that "ImplicitlyWait(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)' in 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35m4v.png)Timeouts' cannot be applied to '(java.time.Duration)'
Please , see the code

```
public class ThirdClassHW3 {

    WebDriver driver ;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    public void waitFirstMode() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver 2");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you believe you faced the issue or did you face it? There is an error showing up, what does it say? Also there's an obvious semicolon missing in your code. No need for images, please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: if the method signature for ImplicityWait is `(long, TimeUnit)`, you can know without looking anywhere else that a single argument isn't going to do it.  so you'd need something like ImplicitlyWait(10L,TimeUnit.SECONDS )

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the java selenium dependencie version you are using

this dependecie is working fine:

```
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
               <version>4.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

some higher version can cause the problem